# Python - Beautiful Soup - extract text between <div> and <sup>

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

[HTML content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNwLX.png)

I have a webpage to parse. The HTML code is in the figure.

I need to extract the price, which is simple text:

```
<div class="price">
"212,25 € "
<sup>HT</sup>
```

This is the only "price" class on the page. So I call the find() method:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(get(url, headers=headers, params=params).content, 'lxml')
container = soup.find_all('div', class_="side-content") # Find a container
cost = container.find('div', {'class': 'price'}) # Find price class
cost_value = cost.next_sibling
```

The cost is *None*. I have tried .next_sibling function and .text functions. But as find() returns *None*, I have an exception. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the expected output? Only `212,25 € ` or do you need the `HT`?

Comment: Only  `212,25 €`

Comment: Why do you need to find the container if there is only one "div" with class "price"?

Comment: @Michael Butscher To attribute the names for other extraction functions. There are several containers and several values to extract from each.

Comment: If "cost" is None the price-div isn't in the container so using of this container is wrong.

Comment: @Michael Butscher
You are right. When I'm trying to extract parent container, some data field are empty. Looks like this price is auto-generated and I can access it from browser, but not with BS requests.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because text is provided as an image. The canonical is *[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*.

Comment: Please review *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)* and *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the needful](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71311069/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it. The problem was in the JavaScript-generated data. So static parsing methods don't work with it. I tried several solutions (including Selenium and an [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) script results capturing).

Finally, inside my parsed data I have found a static URL of a page that links to a separate web page, where this JavaScript code is executed and can be parsed by static methods.

The video *"[Python Web Scraping Tutorial: scraping dynamic JavaScript/Ajax websites with Beautiful Soup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fcKKZMFbyA)"* explains a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is:

```py
cost = cost.find(text=True).strip()
```

Where we `find()` all the text, and `strip()` any whitespaces.

`find(text=True)` limits the output to the `<div>` so it will ignore the nested `<sup>`

---

Regarding the container:

> This is the only "price" class on the page

Then why bother? Just search for the price

---

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="price">
    "212,25 € "
<sup>HT</sup>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

cost = soup.find('div', {'class': 'price'})
cost = cost.find(text=True).strip()

print(cost)
```

Will output:

```
212,25 €
```